# R Error in .jcall(rp, "I", "fetch", stride, block) : java.sql.SQLException: Value is not a number: java.lang.String

Tags: r, jdbc, presto, rstudio-server

I am running a simple sql query in R (using Rstudio). The connection is using Presto driver.

I can run a simple query `Select count(*) from schema.mytable` with no issues. However, as soon as I try to run `Select * from schema.mytable` i get the following error

```
df_zdld001 <- dbGetQuery(conn, input_sql)
Error in .jcall(rp, "I", "fetch", stride, block) : 
  java.sql.SQLException: Value is not a number: java.lang.String
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It seems that you have some type mismatch between data and schema, you will need to fix that.

Comment: I was able to cast a test column as numeric and make the query work. However there are several other such columns. Is there a way to parse the sql as to cast every column as a varchar at read? That ways, I can update the necessary columns directly in R and not have to worry about either the type or manually casting every single column.